# An extra blank line in a vcat in the wl-pprint package

Tags: haskell, pretty-print

I use [wl-pprint](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/wl-pprint) package, because the standard PrettyPrinter lacks functionality. All is good, except an empty doc in a `vcat` function (the same thing with `<$>` combinator).

Correct behavior:

```
import Text.PrettyPrint
> vcat[text "a", empty, text "b"]   
a
b
```

wl-pprint shows an extra blank line:

```
import Text.PrettyPrint.Leijen
> vcat[text "a", empty, text "b"]   
a

b
```

So what can I do? It is imposible to filter vcat list, because there is no `Eq` instance for `Doc`.

Comment: looks like the lib could use an `isEmpty` function, or somesuch thing. Contact the package author, and possibly send him a patch that will work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because I hadn't have any better ideas, I made the following changes in the source

```
(<$$>) :: Doc -> Doc -> Doc
x <$$> Empty    = x                   -- <<< added
Empty <$$> y    = y                   -- <<< added
x <$$> y        = x <> linebreak <> y
```

Answer (score 0):

define
`vcatSoft = fold <//>`

The [docs](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/wl-pprint/1.0/doc/html/Text-PrettyPrint-Leijen.html) say "The document (vcat xs) concatenates all documents xs vertically with ().", and looking at `<$$>`, it says it "concatenates document x and y with a linebreak in between." But notice the next function, `<//>`, which uses a `softbreak` instead.  And looking at the [defn](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/wl-pprint/1.0/doc/html/src/Text-PrettyPrint-Leijen.html) of vcat, it's simply `vcat = fold <$$>`, so define a function `= fold <//>`.

Comment: This function already exists (fillCat), but it returns “ab” inline

Comment: Argh, I knew I should've tested this.  Reading more closely:  Although empty has no content, it does have a 'height' of 1 and behaves exactly like (text "") (and is therefore not a unit of <$>).